# How to get a file from aws s3 and then attach it to a Jira ticket using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, jira

How would I go about grabbing a file from an aws s3 bucket and then attach it to an issue which will be pushed to Jira using aws lambda using python.

Answer (score 0):

The code would download a file from Amazon S3 using the [boto3 AWS SDK for Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

Then the code would add the attachment to a JIRA issue using the [JIRA API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-attachments/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-attachments-post).